# Django makemigrations error?

Tags: python, django, django-manage.py, makemigrations

[image: django makemigrations error]

I'm new started to Django.where is my fault?

Comment: You could show the models.py code, I think you're using strange characters.

Comment: model.py https://ibb.co/ehUYO7

Comment: @FATİHİLGİN just try to add at the top of models.py this `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as suggested in link provided by @Ashish Nitin Patil

Comment: The problem is in the comments. the third letter of `baska` causes the problem

Comment: @neverwalkaloner thank you ıt solved.ıt was very simple missing